# Storing and Displaying Image using Glide & FireBase android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to upload and display the profile picture using Glide & Firebase. Upload part is successfully working. But if i try to load that image from Database its showing blank.My motive is to load the profile_image while the user entered into the activity once and he can tap on the existing image and change that for his wish.

My code

```
public class User extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri filePath;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    private void loadImage(){

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert bundle != null;
        final String retrievedName = bundle.getString("Name");

        // Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
        StorageReference storageReference  = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(retrievedName).child("images/profile_image");
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    // Load the image using Glide
        Glide.with(User.this.getApplicationContext())
                .load(storageReference)
                .into(imageView );
    }


    private void uploadImage() {

        if(filePath != null)
        {

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            assert bundle != null;
            final String retrievedName = bundle.getString("Name");

            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(retrievedName).child("images/profile_image");
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(User.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(User.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null )
        {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                uploadImage();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        loadImage();

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    chooseImage();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

At upload part, I added the url in Realtime database

```
url_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(retrievedName).child("Url");
        StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(retrievedName).child("images/profile_image");
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl =
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        uploadImageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

                        url_db.setValue(uploadImageUrl);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(User.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

While loading that I used this Url from Database and used in Glide

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

    url_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(retrievedName).child("Url");

    url_db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            if(url!= null){

                imageLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                Glide.with( User.this)
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageView);

                imageLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks for the support guys.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As is told in the official firebase documentation [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419) you should `getDownloadURL()` of your photo in order to pass it to your glide library, this way glide will show up your image

in this line add `getDownloadUrl();`

```
    StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(retrievedName).child("images/profile_image").getDownloadUrl();
```

and then just call your image with glide

```
// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(ref)
        .into(imageView);
```

in order to use FirebaseImageLoader() just remember to add this in your gradle

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
```

Also follow up [THIS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage) GitHub link on how to load an image from a `StorageReference`

Another easier way is getting that `DownloadUrl` and use it in glide

```
ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                         @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = 
                     taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    uploadImageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "url to your file..."+uploadImageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(User.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

uploadImageUrl is a global variable `private String uploadImageUrl;`

And then just load that image url with glide into your imageView

```
Glide.with(this /* your_context */)
    .load(uploadImageUrl)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: `StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(retrievedName).child("images/profile_image").getDownloadUrl();` in this line i am getting error....

and also `.using` cannot resolved

Comment: But i need the load value at the start of Activity.... Not after upload. Loading the image before uploading next one.

Comment: so , you should first store your image into your database with the download url to access it , if your first image is into storage  , the links i have provided must help you